# How to handle concurrent Insert JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How to handle concurrent insert in Hibernate or JDBC.

Lets say below scenario needs to be checked before insert.

```
select count(1) from XYZ;
if(cnt>2)
throw exception;
else 
insert into table
```

Now multiple threads try to insert record at same time , there are very good chances that below code will fail.

How to handle such cases properly

Comment: You can use `@Version` from JPA or change your database transaction isolation or use `SELECT ... FOR UDATE`.  See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking.

Comment: @jocki select for update doesn't work when row you're selecting does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You will require table level lock on the table `XYZ` to get correct count, and not allow other transactions to modify the count.

so in JDBC:

1. open connection
2. acquire lock on the table XYZ
3. query the table for count
4. if count is not-ok rollback the connection. This will release the
   lock
5. else insert
6. commit the transaction. this will release the lock

Not sure if it is possible in JPA to achieve table level lock.